# Disable Navbar toggle

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-navbar

I am using the navbar in jquery mobile like this

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"> 
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top" style="text-decoration:none;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="#back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="top">Back</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="#refresh" data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="top">Refresh</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to disable the toggle, so I use data-tap-toggle="false" in the footer. But when I click on refresh, it toggles:

[image]

I already tried to add data-tap-toggle="false" to the navbar div. But it is still not working.

Comment: try adding this function when you refresh `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight()`.

Comment: @Omar: nope, does not work

Comment: i guess the problem is here `onclick="#refresh"`, how do you refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved in [Navbar buttons stay pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11924743/846664)